# How to convert sql query to codeigniter active records

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

How to convert sql query to codeigniter active records

**Query :**

```
 SELECT s2.hierarchy_users_id, 
           s2.commisions, 
           s1.given_amount 
    FROM  (SELECT hierarchy_users_id, 
                  Sum(commisions) AS commisions 
           FROM   commision 
           GROUP  BY hierarchy_users_id = '2') AS s2 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT hierarchy_users_id, 
                                 Sum(given_amount)AS given_amount 
                          FROM   incentives 
                          GROUP  BY hierarchy_users_id = '2')AS s1 
                       ON s1.hierarchy_users_id = s2.hierarchy_users_id 
    LIMIT  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this codeignitor active records query.

**Query:-**

```
$this->db->select('s2.hierarchy_users_id, s2.commisions, s1.given_amount ',false);
$this->db->from('SELECT hierarchy_users_id, Sum(commisions) AS commisions FROM   commision WHERE hierarchy_users_id = "'.$ids[$o].'" GROUP  BY hierarchy_users_id) AS s2');
$this->db->join('SELECT hierarchy_users_id, Sum(given_amount)AS given_amount FROM   incentives WHERE hierarchy_users_id = "'.$ids[$o].'" GROUP  BY hierarchy_users_id) AS s1','s1.hierarchy_users_id = s2.hierarchy_users_id','left outer');
$this->db->limit('1');
$query_result = $this->db->get();
$result = $query_result->result();
return !empty($result) ? $result : '';
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('s2.hierarchy_users_id, s2.commisions, s1.given_amount ',false);
$this->db->from('SELECT hierarchy_users_id, Sum(commisions) AS commisions FROM   commision GROUP  BY hierarchy_users_id) AS s2');
$this->db->join('SELECT hierarchy_users_id, Sum(given_amount)AS given_amount FROM   incentives GROUP  BY hierarchy_users_id) AS s1','s1.hierarchy_users_id = s2.hierarchy_users_id','left outer');
$this->db->limit('1');
$query_result = $this->db->get();
$result = $query_result->result();
return !empty($result) ? $result : '';
```

You can try with first option (hierarchy_users_id = "2") otherwise try second option (all hierarchy_users_id)

I hope it will help.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum(commisions) AS commisions FROM commision GROUP BY hierarchy_users_id = '1' at line 2

Comment: @logicArjun Please check my updated answer with two option.

Comment: Please post your table structure with simple data.

Comment: Got the result:- $this->db->select('s2.hierarchy_users_id, s2.commisions, s1.given_amount ',false);
        
$this->db->from("(SELECT hierarchy_users_id, sum(commisions) AS commisions FROM   commision WHERE commision.hierarchy_users_id= '$ids[$o]' GROUP  BY hierarchy_users_id) AS s2");
$this->db->join("(SELECT hierarchy_users_id, sum(given_amount)AS given_amount FROM   incentives WHERE incentives.hierarchy_users_id= '$ids[$o]' GROUP  BY hierarchy_users_id) AS s1","s1.hierarchy_users_id = s2.hierarchy_users_id",'left outer');